# How does prefix summing the count histogram in counting sort result in an array of output indices?

Tags: algorithms, sorting, arrays, integer-programming, integers

My implementation of counting sort is [based on the description I found here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/). I've also included my code in [this REPL](https://repl.it/repls/SnowEveryModel), but here it is:

```
def counting_sort(input_list, max_int):

  # Make a histogram array for occurences of each integer
  count = [0] * (max_int + 1)
  for i in range(len(input_list)):
    value = input_list[i]
    count[value] += 1

  # count -> [0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]

  # Prefix sum the count histogram array
  modified_count = [i for i in count]
  for i in range(1, len(count)):
    modified_count[i] = modified_count[i-1] + modified_count[i]

  # modified_count -> [0, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7]

  # Output elements from input_list according to modified_count
  output = [0] * len(input_list)     
  for i in range(len(input_list)):
    output_value = input_list[i]
    output_index = modified_count[output_value] - 1
    output[output_index] = output_value
    modified_count[input_list[i]] -= 1

  print("Output", output)

counting_sort([1,5,7,6,2,1,2], 7)
```

Most of this algorithm makes sense to me:

- The algorithm makes a histogram of occurrences where `count[i]` is the number of occurrences.
- Then we prefix sum this `count` histogram which gives us `modified_count`—an array that stores the number of items with a key less than `i`.
- We then use that array to determine the index of the integer in the output array.

The [Wikipedia article states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), that the `modified_count` array, which stores the number of items with a key less than `i`, is the same as an array where each item is the "the first index at which an item with key `i` should be stored in the output array."

That quote from Wikipedia is what I don't understand.

In a nutshell, my question is: *Why is the number of items with a key less than `i` the same as the first output array index for an item with key `i`*. It seems so clever, but very mystifying (currently).

Comment: Can you check what is happening if you run on a smaller example such as [2,2,2,3,3]?

Comment: Oops, thanks for catching that; I really appreciate it! :D I wasn't initializing the `output` array properly. I had `output = [0] * max_int` when I should've had `output = [0] * len(input_list)` so I was getting off-by-one errors. I fixed it in my repl and in the original question.

Comment: Suppose you have a sorted array and you want to know how many elements are smaller than $x$. You just find the index of $x$ in the array and that's your answer. This is the same principle but in reverse.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you for that insight! I was overthinking this. That's so obvious in hindsight. Much obliged! What a clever algorithm. I hope somebody may benefit from my silliness.